# Im making a menu that uses the arrow keys to navigate it, but it doesnt work

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game with a menu that uses left and right arrow keys to navigate it. The issue is when you press one of the arrows, it rapidly switches between the two. I'm assuming I need to use `pygame.KEYUP`, but i'm not sure how to use it. Right now it just flickers between Play and Quit. Here's my code. I want it so if you press left or right it selects play or quit and doesn't flicker between both.

```
'''
Mega Maro Bois

Zan3yGameZ 2018
'''

import pygame, time

pygame.init()

def createWindow():
    global WIDTH, HEIGHT, TITLE, W
    WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 450
    TITLE = "Mega Maro Bois"
    pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
    W = pygame.display.set_mode( (WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF )

createWindow()


menu = pygame.image.load("Graphics\\Menu.png")
############################################################# PLAY PICTURES
play = pygame.image.load("Graphics\\Play.png")
play_sel = pygame.image.load("Graphics\\Play_Selected.png")
############################################################# QUIT PICTURES
quit = pygame.image.load("Graphics\\Quit.png")
quit_sel = pygame.image.load("Graphics\\Quit_Selected.png")


Event = "Menu"

loop = True

Button_Sel = "Play"
Button_Sel2 = 1


if Event == "Menu":
    W.blit(menu, (0, 0))
    W.blit(play, (25, 250))
    W.blit(quit, (435, 250))

while loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    if Event == "Menu":

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                Button_Sel = "Play"
            if event.key == pygame.K_2:
                Button_Sel = "Quit"
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Button_Sel2 += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Button_Sel2 -= 1


            #################################################################ENTER SELECT
            if Button_Sel == "Play" and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                Event = "Play"
            if Button_Sel == "Quit" and event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            #################################################################SPACE SELECT
            if Button_Sel == "Play" and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                Event = "Play"
            if Button_Sel == "Quit" and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()                      


        ###################################################IF USER SELECTS PLAY
        if Button_Sel == "Play":
            W.blit(play_sel, (25, 250))
            W.blit(quit, (435, 250))
        ###################################################IF USER SELECTS QUIT
        if Button_Sel == "Quit":
            W.blit(play, (25, 250))
            W.blit(quit_sel, (435, 250))

        if Button_Sel2 == 1:
            Button_Sel = "Play"
        if Button_Sel2 == 2:
            Button_Sel = "Quit"


    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

I mostly just need to know how to use `pygame.KEYUP` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` is outside the event dealing loop `for event in pygame.event.get():`

That means you keep processing the same event over and over

Put the event check inside the loop.

Comment: Well, the question is answered, maybe you should ask another question with the updated code

Comment: I just got rid of the pressing 1 and 2 function, thanks for da help